# .dockerignore workflow unclear

Tags: docker, dockerignore

I have a question about the **.dockerignore** workflow which I wasn't really able to understand while browsing through the documentation and different internet topics.

Have the following folder structure:

```
home
   |
   |- folder_1
   |- folder_2
```

Inside my dockerfile I want to copy the contents of **home** directory, so I use

```
COPY ./ /home
```

Inside **.dockerignore** I have:

```
*
!folder_1
!folder_3
```

I am referring to a non-existent folder - **folder_3**, which is supposed to be copied, right?
I ran it and it looks like there's no problem with that, thus **.dockerignore** somehow manages this situation.

If I tried to do the same thing without using **.dockerignore**, targeting a non-existent directory I would get an error.

If anybody can please clear this workflow, or if a duplicate, please attach some information so I can educate myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you expecting some kind of error because `folder_3` doesn't exist? `!folder_3` only tells docker that if that folder was previously excluded by a previous line in this file, then ignore that and copy this file/folder anyway. Just like with a `.gitignore` file you can put tons of rules in there that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Well clearly there's not an error, but since you are trying to copy a non-existent file/directory in the COPY command, I suspected that this would be a problem.

Comment: You are looking at it the wrong way. `COPY` will copy everything. Then on top of that the rules in `.dockerignore` tell is which files to exclude from copying. So the fact that there is a rule to exclude something that doesn't exist or not exclude something that doesn't exist is irrelevant. A very common way to use these files are to make 1 extensive ignore file with tons of rules that you can use in all your projects, instead of having one custom file for each project.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like I got the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `.dockerignore` works like `.gitignore`. Inside these files you set the rules on the basis of which files should be added, and which should not.

In your scenario you `COPY` the whole **home** directory which consists of **folder_1** and **folder_2**. Your `.dockerignore` file sets the following rules:

```
*           # ignore all files/directories
!folder_1   # do not ignore folder_1
!folder_3   # do not ignore folder_3
```

Regardless of whether there is a `folder_1` or `folder_3` in your local **home** directory or not, it won't show you any errors, because it just tries to find particular files/directories that are inside `.dockerignore`. If it finds this file/directory, it applies the rules. If it doesn't find this file/directory, it doesn't do anything with it.

Hope that's a little bit more clear now.

Comment: Yes, I understood, thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You'll occasionally see reference to a Docker *build context*.  The build has two steps:

1. The `docker build` client application creates a tar file of its directory parameter, and sends it in an HTTP request to the Docker daemon.
2. The Docker daemon unpacks the tar file, finds the `Dockerfile` in it, and runs it using the file content it was given.

`.dockerignore` only affects the first step: it keeps `docker build` from sending the Docker daemon particular files.  The `.dockerignore` file doesn't require there to be a `folder_3` directory, it just says that if there is one it shouldn't be excluded.  The second step on the Docker daemon side doesn't use `.dockerignore` at all, and when you `COPY . /somewhere` it copies the entire build context; that is, whatever was sent in the API request.

There are a couple of practical consequences of this workflow.  If you have a very large local directory it can take time to send it to the Docker daemon, and the Docker daemon keeps a duplicate copy of it during the build, so it's often worthwhile to `.dockerignore` your `.git` directory and a build tree.  This setup is also how `docker build` works with a Docker daemon on a different system or in a VM, and it's why if you try to `COPY` a file by name that doesn't exist (`COPY folder_3 somewhere`) you get an error message referencing a Docker-internal path.